# JS: Loaded json undefined, even though it is not

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to load an array via json with this function I mostly stole from W3 schools:

```
function load_json_data(path, callback) {
  var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4 && httpRequest.status === 200) {
      var data = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
      if (callback) callback(data);
    }
  };
  httpRequest.open('GET', path);
  httpRequest.send();
}
```

I have a second function that is supposed to graph the data, but let's pretend it just prints the array. (It also doesn't graph them so it's not just a display error):

```
function create_graph(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

Now, outside of any function, I am doing this:

```
var data;
load_json_data(
  "./test.json",
  function(return_data) {
    data = return_data;
  }
);
console.log("Loaded Data: " + data)
create_graph(data);
```

So I'm loading "./test.json" and passing that to the function.
Unfortunately the output says, data is undefined, but when I access the variable manually I get the right output:

```
Loaded Data: undefined
Received Data: undefined
> data
(6) [0.6, 0.55, 0.45, 0.4, 0.7, 0.66]
```

I'm coming from c and python so I'm assuming the interpreter is hiding something from me. Why is the variable undefined after the load function ran, but defined, when I access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you provide a callback that sets `data`, you're basically telling JS "make the HTTP request, set the `data` variable when it's done, but in the meantime keep running the code that comes afterwards." If you want `data` to be set, you have to move the code that uses `data` into the callback:

```js
var data;
load_json_data(
  "./test.json",
  function(return_data) {
    data = return_data;
    console.log("Loaded Data: " + data)
    create_graph(data);
  }
);
```

You should also consider migrating to the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) as well as using [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```js
function load_json_data(path, callback) {
  return fetch(path).then(res => res.json());
}

load_json_data("./test.json", function(data) {
  console.log("Loaded data: " + data);
  create_graph(data);
});
```